# Is there have an alternative API for GestureListener.Flick?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a WP Silverlight 8.1 app, compiler always reports a C0618 warning, this is because Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureService is obsolete in Windows Phone 8 and I use it, is there have an alternative API for GestureService.GetGestureListener(..).Flick?

Comment: Your question is confusing. `GestureListener` is available in WP8 toolkit. There's no `GestureListener` (there's `GestureRecognizer` instead ) in the new WP8.1 runtime. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question again. Though I can still use GestureListener in WP Silverlight 8.1 app, but as document said this API will be obsoleted by Microsoft in furture, so here I would like to ask who is its replacement?

Comment: You are still safe to use it in SL8.1, once you develop it in RT, you will need to use GestureRecognizer instead.